# What does this mean: ${somevalue}

Tags: java, xml

I use this many times in my XML codes:

```
${some.value}
```

where some.value may come from

1. Properties file
2. System.setProperty("some.value", "any_value");

**Example:**

In case of spring context,

```
 <bean id="placeholderConfig"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location" value="classpath:test.properties" />
        </bean>

<bean id="anyID" class="com.my.package.MyClass" >
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${some.value}" />
    </bean>
```

And test.properties is,

```
some.value=any_value
```

What are they called?

What exactly are them?

Comment: Where do you encounter this, by change in Eclipse/Ant java build XML files?

Comment: variables which will get populated at runtime from Property file

Comment: @KevinBowersox Spring as an example. Check my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System Properties :** 
It is common property file for your machine which maintained by Java in `java.lang.System` class. Here is the detail document for [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

 when you set `System.setProperty("some.value", "any_value");` you can access the value of property anywhere in your java program by calling `System.getproperty("some.value");`

**Properties file:**

A file that is saved in format of `Key & Value` pair with new line separator and `.properties` is the extension of file. Java doc for [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the places where you configure such things are XML / property files. Spring calls them `property-placeholders`. Usually such variables can be loaded at run-time.